# Meta description changed out of the blue

Tags: wordpress, metadata, meta-tags

I am currently experiencing a problem with my google results. My meta description has been changed to characters I know nothing about for no reason. Normally here was the description that is on my home page, but that is suddenly gone. (see the screenshot for clarification).

I've tried a lot of things to adjust the meta description, but unfortunately I can't figure it out and this is a bad image for my company.

It concerns the website [www.webrange.nl](http://www.webrange.nl) that I built with wordpress. Does anyone have any tips or maybe a way to solve this? So that the description returns to normal.

[image]

I have changed the description in the head of the website:

All-in webdevelopment

And also changed it with a seo plugin, and in the theme it self.

Comment: Welcome!  Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **add transcriptions** of your images of text into actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting).

Comment: [edit] to also show the text you expect to see. Even better if you can provide steps to reproduce the issue (a [mre]).

Answer (score 0):

Description displayed on google results can be different from the meta description of your website for multiples reasons.

Google crawlers doesn't crawl websites everytime, there may be a delay of few hours to few days between your meta description modification and the moment when google update the description displayed on search results.

As we can see and your page, the meta description seems correct. It 's possible that you already fixed your problem but you'll have to wait for Google to update it on their side.
You can check google search console to force a new indexation of your page, or (re)send your xml sitemap. It can accelerate the process.

Also, keep in mind that Google can use an excerpt of your page content instead of your meta description if Google decides that the excerpt he found on your page is more relevant than your meta description, depending on keyword searched by the user. Example : You have a page talking about cars, and the user search for "engine" in google. If your meta description does not contain the word "engine" but your page content has a text containing it, there is high probability that Google display a description with an excerpt of that content instead of your meta description. It can be confusing